# How to change from c99 to gcc in Xcode (Mac OS X)?

Tags: xcode, gcc, c99

I have a problem with my xcode. The thin is that my teacher can't execute my code just because I use C99. I've tried to change it but without any results, I have installed command line tool too whithout any result. Because of that I installed Netbeans IDE 7.4 and tried to program there. To test which standard the program used I tried with a loop `(int i = 0; i< size; i++)` and the program complained which is a good sign. Now two days later I got the same problem with Netbeans too and I am really near to just jump off the course because of this issue. I'm late with my assignment just because my teacher doesn't accept my assignments written with c99 standard etc. 
Someone who has have same issues and solved the problem? It doesn't really matter if it's on Netbeans or Xcode. I just wanna code.

If you can't help me, whats the difference between c99 and c90 etc? I know that with the for loop but are there any other things that makes the code unexecutable?

When I type gcc --version on the terminal I get this...

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
John-MacBook-Air:~ johnBlunt$

Here is my settings 
[image: The compiler is a Apple LLVM 5.0. I don't know if it matters]

[image: The C language dialect is c89 [-std= c89]

[image: And I have set the settings to treat the warnings as errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** updated to reflect updated question.

Clang and GCC shouldn't have any noticeable differences to most code aside from some default warnings IIRC. what is your specific problem? Is it that you are compiling a binary on a mac and your teacher is on windows? your teacher needs to tell you the errors if you want to fix them.

If you do want to use GCC with xcode you need to download and install it separately.

I dont know what CGG is, but you can change the setting by selecting your project/target in xcode then going to "build settings" then change the "c language dialect" setting.

AFIK there is no C90 do you mean C89? why in the world does your teacher insist on using that?! we are up to C11 now...

Comment: Opps I will edit it. I mean gcc not cgg, my bad. I don't know why he insist using that. Yeah I mean C89. I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge. I'm a beginner in C

Comment: I changed the dialect to C89[-std=c89] but nothing happens. It still accepts a declaration in a for loop for(int i = 0 ...)

Comment: What he complained to was that the inner declaration in a for loop. I fixed that but he insisted that I should change to c89 standard. Yes I think he is on a window plattform. Do you know where I can download gcc and install it?

Comment: do you not even get a warning for that using c89? you can try adding the -pedantic flag to the "other c flags" field. also it shouldnt be required but you can try cleaning the build to force a full recompile.

Comment: should I type -pedantic or -pedantic flag? I tried both versions but I can't see any difference...

Comment: I have just confirmed that changing to c89 and adding the `-pedantic` flag will generate a warning for that loop. you can also enable warnings as errors if you wish.

Comment: Nothing helped. I tried (cmd + alt + shift + k) for cleaning the build but I aren't getting any warning. I also enabled warnings as errors but I don't get any errors.

Comment: then you either don't have the correct settings (did you chage C++ settings instead of C?) or possible on an old version of xcode.

Comment: I see in your screenshot that you have pedantic warnings off. they need to be on.

Comment: this is so frustrating because nothing works. I did exactly as you said but I don't see any difference.

Comment: Oh I think I got it! The settings didn't work because it was an old project with old settings. When I tried with a new project it worked excellent! Thanks @Brad